# How does a client (browser) generate a request to be sent to a Server?

Tags: http, client, request, network-protocols

Once a user hits a URL the local machine does a lookup on the hosts file to see if there are any entries, if not the local machine pings some DNS (how? where?) to resolve the URL and get the associated IP address... Once it gets the IP it opens a socket channel on that IP address and interacts with the server...

Is this accurate?

I'm trying to understand step by step and in detail, how the request is generated and sent over to a server.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: If you want to understand in detail I don't think you should ask on stackoverflow. You should start some serious reading (including RFCs).

Comment: *(how? where?)* You internet connection has a DNS server associated. Lookup starts from there and jumps from server to server until it finds the correct IP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:An_example_of_theoretical_DNS_recursion.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about a TCP connection. The client will, as you say, do a lookup in its hosts file; if there is not an entry, it will look up its first configured DNS server (based either on manual configuration or DHCP settings) and initiate a connection to that server. Once the client has the address of the desired server, it will send a SYN packet to that server, which will reply with a SYN/ACK, and the client will reply with an ACK packet to establish the connection. This is the [TCP handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment). Once the connection is established, the client and server communicate over their respective sockets, passing data through the layers of the TCP protocol and sending error-correction and metadata packets to coordinate with each other. This information contains the type of request, usually, dependent on protocol. For HTTP, this is usually a GET or POST request, which is responded to by the server appropriately. If you want more specific information, can you post what kind of protocol you're curious about?

Comment: DHCP settings -- I see... Thanks for sharing this detailed networking info. I only have a loose understanding of tcp/ip, but im generally interested in understanding what goes on with an http request. So far this is aweswome!

Answer (score 4):

For a very detailed overview of how DNS works, see [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) and for how HTTP works see [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

These are the canonical documents. They get very detailed, but if you stick to the Overall Operations sections and lookup those parts you need clarification on, they can be very helpful.

Basically for any protocol you want an explanation for (at a deeper level you might want to see TCP), the most detailed place to get information is the RFCs.

Comment: Why didn't you post the direct links from IETF?

Comment: Changed, I was just kind of going with the first hit from google.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You ae more and less correct.

It looks on the hosts file and then in DNS. On linux machine you can change the order in etc/resolv.conf file.

Your primary DNS server is configured in your tcp/ip settings. DNS is using port UDP/53 for such requested. if your DNS can't resolve the host name it forwards it to parent DNS, but this is another topic. 
After it's getting IP address it's opening socket to the server using address (IP + port).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[image: http://betterexplained.com/wp-content/uploads/compression/HTTP_request.png]

Comment: Although a pretty picture, I don't think this really answers the question in the desired depth and technical sense.